# Mimic nest nested ListView behavior

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

How do you mimic the nested ListView behavior seen [in this Google I/O 2014 Material Design talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZqzz5lZFvo&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJQe6T9CKafiDm7p_LCCx6F#t=1041)?

In this example, at the root level there is a listview with two items: 
- Profile image
- Another listview at the bottom

Initially, scrolling shouldn't have any effect the listview containing contacts. It should just shrink the profile image into the action bar.

Once this is completed, the ListView with contacts should start receiving scroll events.

What's the best way to get this behavior?